# "Odd" behavior when clicking on li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to add a class to dynamically generated `<li>` elements, but it has a very strange behavior. With a single `<li>` it works perfectly, but after adding an another element, the `class` attribute will be added without value. After adding the third `<li>` it will work again (basically it works only if the number of the `<li>` elements is odd).

```js
var JSTasker = {
  updateTaskCounter: function() {
    var taskCount = $('div#tasks ul').children().not('li.completed').size();
    $('span#task_counter').text(taskCount);
  },
  sortTasks: function() {
    var taskList = $('div#tasks ul');
    var allCompleted = $(taskList).children('.completed');
    allCompleted.detach();
    allCompleted.appendTo(taskList);
  },
  updatePage: function() {
    this.updateTaskCounter();
    this.sortTasks();
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#task_text').focus();
  $('form#add_task').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var taskText = $('input#task_text').val();
    var taskItem = "<li>" + taskText + "</li>";
    $('div#tasks ul').append(taskItem);
    $('input#task_text').val(null);
    JSTasker.updatePage();
    $('div#tasks ul').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('completed');
      JSTasker.updatePage();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
h1,
h2,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html {
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans Light', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';
  font-size: 90%;
}
body {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
fieldset {
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
input[type=text] {
  width: 300px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
input[type=submit] {} #tasks {
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h2 span#task_counter {
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #999;
}
#tasks ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#tasks ul li {
  padding: 6px 10px 3px 20px;
  height: 1.6em;
}
#tasks ul li:hover {
  background: #FFF8DC;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#tasks ul li.completed {
  background: url('icons/accept.png') no-repeat 0px 5px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #999;
}
.trash {
  float: right;
  padding: 2px;
}
.trash:hover {
  background: #F99;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Tasker</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='JSTasker.css' />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="JSTasker.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>JSTasker</h1>
  <form id='add_task'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Add a Task</legend>
      <input type='text' name='task_text' id='task_text' />
      <input type='submit' name='add_button' value='Add' />
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div id='tasks'>
    <h2>Your Tasks <span id='task_counter'></span></h2>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the problematic part:

```
    $('div#tasks ul').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass('completed');
        JSTasker.updatePage();
    });
```

The application is based on [this](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/javascript/jquery/jstasker.html) tutorial.

Comment: your code is working, it is toggling class correctly and sorting the result (i.e. putting striked text in the last)

Comment: Try adding two tasks, then click on them to apply 'completed' class. It will not apply. As I mentioned in the description, it works perfectly, but only when the number of the tasks is odd. If the number is even, it will not apply the 'completed' class.

Comment: intrestingly, this problem occurs only when there are two elements in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add onclick handler outside form submit, right now your onclick event is being initialized every time you submit the form. but `$().on()` is for dynamic binding and you need to call it only once

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input#task_text').focus();

  $('form#add_task').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var taskText = $('input#task_text').val();
    var taskItem = "<li>" + taskText + "</li>";
    $('div#tasks ul').append(taskItem);
    $('input#task_text').val("");

    JSTasker.updatePage();

  });
    $('div#tasks ul').on('click', "li", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('completed');
      JSTasker.updatePage();

    });

});
```

Comment: Ooh, thanks a lot. I've tried all the combinations but this. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are binding click event to `li` for every click of add button. Take this code out and it will work. It was working for odd number of elements because it will bind event odd times. lets say you added 3 `li`s and hence it will call click event 3 times. first time add class, then remove and then add class again. But it will fail for even number of `li`s as it will first add class and then remove it.

```js
var JSTasker = {
  updateTaskCounter: function() {
    var taskCount = $('div#tasks ul').children().not('li.completed').size();
    $('span#task_counter').text(taskCount);
  },
  sortTasks: function() {
    var taskList = $('div#tasks ul');
    var allCompleted = $(taskList).children('.completed');
    allCompleted.detach();
    allCompleted.appendTo(taskList);
  },
  updatePage: function() {
    this.updateTaskCounter();
    this.sortTasks();
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#task_text').focus();
  $('form#add_task').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var taskText = $('input#task_text').val();
    var taskItem = "<li>" + taskText + "</li>";
    $('div#tasks ul').append(taskItem);
    $('input#task_text').val(null);
    JSTasker.updatePage();
  });
  
  $('div#tasks ul').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('completed');
      JSTasker.updatePage();
    });
});
```

```css
h1,
h2,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html {
  background: #333;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans Light', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';
  font-size: 90%;
}
body {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid #EEE;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
fieldset {
  border: 2px solid #CCC;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
input[type=text] {
  width: 300px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
input[type=submit] {} #tasks {
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h2 span#task_counter {
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #999;
}
#tasks ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#tasks ul li {
  padding: 6px 10px 3px 20px;
  height: 1.6em;
}
#tasks ul li:hover {
  background: #FFF8DC;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#tasks ul li.completed {
  background: url('icons/accept.png') no-repeat 0px 5px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #999;
}
.trash {
  float: right;
  padding: 2px;
}
.trash:hover {
  background: #F99;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Tasker</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='JSTasker.css' />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="JSTasker.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>JSTasker</h1>
  <form id='add_task'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Add a Task</legend>
      <input type='text' name='task_text' id='task_text' />
      <input type='submit' name='add_button' value='Add' />
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div id='tasks'>
    <h2>Your Tasks <span id='task_counter'></span></h2>
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works with only odd numbers of tasks because you add a new click handler to every `<li>` each time you submit the form. That means that when you have two `<li>`s, you call `toggleClass` twice, and get nowhere. You can confirm this by adding `alert("hi")` to your current code after the `toggleClass` call.